# How long does it take to get whitelisted (gain production access to the API scopes) by Uber?

Tags: uber-api

As my application is production ready, I have completed all the prerequisite's for the approval, as I have included the privacy policy, Videos, Screenshots and description about my app`s workflow.

I have applied for full access via my developers.uber account.

How long it take to get the full access? Or if I have missed on to something important to get whitelisted, kindly let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for reaching out. On average, we try to respond to requests within 24-48 hours. However, depending on our availability due to travel or holidays, it may take longer.

To request whitelisting, you should go to your app in the [Uber Developers App Console](https://developer.uber.com/dashboard) and request whitelisting for the minimal list of scopes you need for your app to function.

If you've provided all the necessary information (as you state that you did), we'll review your materials and get back to you.

We appreciate your patience in the meantime! Given that it's Memorial Day weekend in the United States this weekend, the team was short-staffed.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response.Worked for me